# Animating with armature and exporting to Unity

Tags: animation, armature, export, unity, .fbx

I've animated a 3D model in blender, using Armature, to impose a wind like animation. [image]

On each wheat head, I've placed a bone and than parented the bone and the wheat head so that once I rotate bone, the wheat head is moving as well, making it look like a wind.

What do I need to do next so the model can be prepared for Unity3d?

I think my problem is that when in Action Editor, instead of seeing one action, called "wind" for example, I see an action for each armature.

[image]

Is there a way to combine 43 actions into one action?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you exporting in ASCII or binary format? You should use ASCII format for importing into Unity. Also, it's normal for it to take a long time to generate the FBX. Some models can take up to 5 minutes. How long does it take your model?

Comment: Hello @TTTTTTa first of all, thanks for the format remark. Up until today it was always the binary file when exporting .fbx, and I now try ASCII.

Comment: Can you tell the difference between the two: Binary or ASCII? It takes up to 20 minutes and then I usually give up.

Comment: So you exported the model as FBX and then re-imported the FBX into Blender? I could be wrong, but I don't think this is fully supported. I have always had issues trying to do that. Note: you are not actually required to generate the FBX yourself. You could just place the .blend file in the Assets/ folder, and let Unity generate the .FBX automatically when it imports the model. I would create a test project in Unity and place the model (.blend) in the assets folder and see what happens. If you still have issues you can upload the file to Blendexchange http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I really don't understand how hard can it be to animate one model. And more than that, all the videos out there are not really helping.